# Delete the last 2 additions to a featuregroup in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a featuregroup that adds circlemarkers and paths -- they are added in sequence and I need a way to create a function that will remove the last (2) in the _layers every time it's clicked.

I tried slicing but that doesn't work because it's not really an array.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? I've been searching stackoverflow for awhile and cannot find anything that matches what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Where's the code? Make a small sample of the working codes and put it here, maybe someone will help. And best of all, add to codepen, codesandbox or other website.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simply refer to Leaflet documentation:

You can use the [methods the layerGroup/featureGroup provides](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) to remove the last two layers from the group.

- The `getLayers` method [returns an array of all the layers added to the group](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayers).
- The `eachLayer` method [iterates over the layers of the group, optionally specifying context of the iterator function](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer).
- The `removeLayer` method [removes the layer with the given internal ID from the group](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-removelayer).

Leaflet's [`featureGroup` is an extension of the `layerGroup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) so all of these will work on `featureGroup` as well.

So, say that you have your layers set up like so:

```js
// Layers:
var layers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(layers);
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  radius: 500,
}).addTo(layers);
var polygon = L.polygon([
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047],
]).addTo(layers);
```

You can use those `layerGroup` methods to remove the last two elements of the array:

```js
// Pass the layerGroup to the function
function removeLastTwo(layerGroup) {
  // Use getLayers to get the array
  var layerArr = layerGroup.getLayers();
  var minusOne = layerArr.length - 1;
  var minusTwo = layerArr.length - 2;
  // Use eachLayer to iterate the layerGroup
  layerGroup.eachLayer((layer) => {
    // Grab the index of the layer
    var layerIndex = layerArr.indexOf(layer);
    // Remove the last two elements of the layerGroup array
    if (layerIndex === minusOne || layerIndex === minusTwo) {
      layerGroup.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  });
}
```

[Here is a live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ddkqhp?file=index.js), with this function attached to the click event listener of a button.

Comment: There is a subtlety that can make this approach behave unexpectedly wrt "last two": getLayers and eachLayer may not iterate in the order of insertion. Leaflet Layer groups internally use a map/dictionary to store their child Layers, with the stamped id (integer) of those as keys. Hence iteration order is based on these integer id's (JS spec). In simple situations, the child layers are created and stamped in the same order as they are inserted. But there is no guarantee in more complex cases.